# Installing Rmagick issues in Mac OS X lion

Tags: macos, operating-system, rubygems, osx-mountain-lion, rmagick

Problem:
    Fetching: rmagick-2.13.2.gem (100%)
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    /Users/officemachine1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
    checking for /usr/bin/gcc-4.2... yes
    checking for Magick-config... yes
    checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
    checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
    /usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 41: pkg-config: command not found
    /usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 47: pkg-config: command not found
    /usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 50: pkg-config: command not found
    /usr/local/bin/Magick-config: line 53: pkg-config: command not found
    checking for stdint.h... yes
    checking for sys/types.h... yes
    checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no
    Can't install RMagick 2.13.2. Can't find MagickWand.h.
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.
    Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/Users/officemachine1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
    Gem files will remain installed in /Users/officemachine1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
    Results logged to /Users/officemachine1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out

Answer (score 1):

Solutions:
$ brew install pkg-config
Error: Permission denied - /Users/officemachine1/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/pkg-config.brewing
office-machine-1s-macbook:nationestateagents officemachine1$ sudo brew install pkg-config
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/pkg-config-0.28.lion.bottle.tar.gz

################################################################## 100.0%

==> Pouring pkg-config-0.28.lion.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.28: 10 files, 636K

$ rvmsudo bundle install

I hope this might be helping you to come out from the above issue.